# .htaccess access parent folder

Tags: .htaccess

I just installed [Apaxy](http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/) for a better and customizable folders views.

It works perfectly, but not in my virtualhost.

**Folder** (localhost) :

[image]

**Virtualhost** (local.dev.conf, access with local.dev):

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName local.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/local.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, in the virtualhost (local.dev) apaxy doesn't work.

I assume it's normal because the server try to find files in local.dev/themes/...

Or my 'themes' folder is in the parent folder, so it is possible to resolve this ?

Here is the .htaccess : 
https://justpaste.it/t8yp

Comment: Your question is not related to docker. You may want to remove this tag. As for your issue, did you try to put the theme dir into the local.dev?

Comment: If i do that, it works, but I don"t want to copy theme folder every virtualhost. If I want to change just 1 style, I have to do that in every virtualhosts

Comment: I see, why not using `links` then?

Comment: And how links works ?

Comment: `man ln`. It can be likened to a shortcut. It links a file from another destination (path). See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks#244250) to enable apache to follow these links. Basically, from a terminal with the server, execute `ln -s /path/to/theme /path/to/local.dev/theme`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. You can answer with this reponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Apache serves file from the directory `/var/www/local.dev`.

#### Solution

Moving the directory `/var/www/theme` into `/var/www/local.dev` would work. Nevertheless if, for any reason, you do not want to move `theme` you can *link* it using the command `ln -s /path/to/theme /path/to/local.dev/theme`.

#### IMHO

Moving the directory would be a better solution as linking it, would force the configuration to enable [`follow-symlink`](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks#244250), as it can be [considered as a security issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/244592/followsymlinks-on-apache-why-is-it-a-security-risk).